# What is the English equivalent of this Russian sentence that says "All things around you have to be sized to you"?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

How do you understand these phrases:

> All things  around you have to be by size [to] [you].

OR

> Everythings around people have to be by size [to] [them].

The phrases consist of:

*all things around you/people* -- wear, books, people, theories, wishes, aims and in one word everything around you and within you

*have to be by size [to] [them/you]* -- your clothes fit to your body, books fit to your brain, people fit to your worldview, etc.

Questions:

1. BY SIZE -- correctness usage in this context
2. interchangeable ALL THINGS and EVERYTHING
3. necessity the pronouns YOU/THEM at the end
4. necessity the preposition TO
5. which of these sentences sounds better
6. how would you say that himself

It is my thought and I don't know how it is sounds for native speakers and do they understand that right.

In Russian I would write it: Все что тебя окружает должно быть соразмерно тебе.

---

Context wherein I want to use it is to advise to himself.

My understanding of these phrases:
I have to take appropriate things no less no more to my ability and my form.

*ablitity/form* -- brain, body, temperament etc.

Comment: Your sentences are not at all idiomatic. _All things_ takes a plural verb, but _everything_ takes a singular verb. No-one would understand what you mean by _by size_.

Comment: When you say "have to be" do you mean "should be" (it is a good thing if they are) or "must be" (it has to be that way). It would help to understand the context that you want to use this sentence in. Google translates your Russian sentence as: Everything that surrounds you should be proportionate to you.

Comment: *Birds of a feather flock together,* might be an English phrase that comes close to meaning something similar to your phrase.  It means living things tend to gather in groups formed of similar looking/thinking/acting/ things.

Comment: Instead of **by size** use **sized**: "All things around you have to be sized to you." This is at least understandable, though the meaning is still not clear (as others have said).

Comment: I'd probably guess you're accusing someone of needing everything around them *tailor-made* to themselves - and not being able to deal with things that aren't. Or *living in a bubble*, in other words.

Comment: @ColleenV - Yes, it had occurred to me that _in proportion to_ might be better than _sized to_.

Comment: Google translates the Russian to the more idiomatic: "*Everything that surrounds you should be proportionate to you*". It's still not clear tome what the intent of the phrase is.

Comment: Is this supposed to mean that it is a good idea to make everything around you fit, or is it suggesting that the person you are talking to is very selfish, and expects everybody else to change for their convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation of this Russian idiom is a little broken, but I think I understand it. It seems to mean that, whatever things you choose should match your style, ability etc. It sounds like it is a very broad idiom that could be used in a number of contexts, from commenting on someone's fashion choices, to their choice of reading material, and beyond.

I cannot think of a directly equivalent English idiom that is so broad, but there are a number of idioms that might express a similar idea in different contexts.

For example, we sometimes use the clothing terms "made to measure" and "tailor-made" in broader contexts. If you thought a book was particularly suitable for a particular person, you might say it was "tailor-made" for them. Likewise, we sometimes use the expressions "it suits you" or "it fits you" beyond clothing - for example, it is often said of new mothers that motherhood 'suits' them, meaning they are doing well in that new role.

If I had to translate it myself, not into a recognised idiom, but into something that makes sense in English, I wouldn't use the word "surround" the way you did. "Everything that surrounds you" sounds like the objects have encircled you. However, we do say that we can "surround ourselves" with things. So, perhaps the best translation would be "You should surround yourself with things that suit you". Or, if you wanted it to sound more like a 'figurative' proverb, you could say "you should wear what fits you", although you might need to go one to explain how that applies.

Comment: @Australbee Thanks for your answer. Your grasp of the phrase match with that I put in it. Writing in that way "everything surrounds you have to be suits to you"  is correct and seems like an aphorism?

Comment: @ИванНепряхин I've added another paragraph with two suggested translations, I hope this helps.

Comment: @Australbee, thanks for your kindness! Your answer is enough for me